# Mongoose returns empy object, works in mongo shell

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get a JSON object returned from my mongoDB using mongoose (latest version). Everything works find but i get an empty array returned [].

**app.js**

```
/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
dependencies
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    var express = require("express")
    var cons = require("consolidate")
    var app = express()

    var db = require("./model/db")

    var path = require("path")
    var routes = require("./routes/routes")

/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
configure
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    app.configure(function(){

        app.use(app.router)
        app.engine("html", cons.hogan)
        app.set("view engine", "html")
        app.set("views", __dirname + "/views")
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
        app.use(express.errorHandler())

    })

/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
routes
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    app.get("/", routes.index)
    app.get("/hire", routes.hire)
    app.get("/hire/:id/:nr", routes.hirePerson)
    app.get("/books", routes.books)
    app.get("/projects", routes.projects)

/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
listen
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    app.listen(2020)
```

**db.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 country: String,
 GroupName: String
});

mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/basingCOM');

var Team = mongoose.model('Team');
Team.find({"GroupName":"kevin"}, function (err, teams) {console.log(teams)})
```

This .find method **works in the shell**, i get the json object returned, but when i'm using it in my node app the console spits out an **empty** object.

```
20 Feb 11:47:06 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
20 Feb 11:47:06 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[]
```

thx for all your help guy's, really appreciate it. I'm getting there slowly but surely thx :)

---

**EDIT 1**

I changed db.js to this (using the comments below), but i still have an empty object.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 country: String,
 GroupName: String
});

var teamModel = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/basingCOM', function(err){doDBstuff(err)});

function doDBstuff(err){

    if (err){throw err}

    console.log("jow")

    teamModel.find({"GroupName":"kevin"}, function (err, teams) {console.log(teams)});

}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

I created a new schema (booksSchema) and tried the code with the booksModel instead of the teamModel. The output was a correct JSON object. So it works with booksModel, but not with teamModel.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true)

var teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 country: String,
 GroupName: String
});

var booksSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: String,
 author: String
});

var teamModel = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);
var booksModel = mongoose.model('books', booksSchema);


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/basingCOM', function(err){doDBstuff(err)});

function doDBstuff(err){

    if (err){throw err}

    booksModel.find(function (err, books) {console.log(books)});

}
```

---

**some console output:**

```
> db.Team.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5305d71aa753d02674ed311c"), "country" : "belgium", "GroupName" : "kevin" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5305d738a753d02674ed311d"), "country" : "holland", "GroupName" : "dave" }
> 

> db.Team.find({"GroupName":"kevin"}, function (err, teams) {console.log(teams)})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5305d71aa753d02674ed311c"), "country" : "belgium", "GroupName" : "kevin" }
```

---

```
>
```

**EDIT 3**

when turning on mongoose.set("debug", true) it shows that the mongo is looking for the data in the collection teams.find() instead of Team.find().

```
20 Feb 13:46:29 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Mongoose: teams.find({}) { fields: undefined }  
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you are executing the query before a connection is established with MongoDB. `mongoose.connect` is an asynchronous function and you have to wait for it's callback to be invoked before you do the query. Try like this...

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/basingCOM', function (err) {
    if (err) 
      throw err;

    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB");
    Team.find({"GroupName":"kevin"}, function (err, teams) {console.log(teams)})
});
```

Comment: I also tried your method, using the callback on connect, but i still have an empty object []

Comment: I just ran the exact code from your EDIT 1 and I got a non-empty array in the console. So the code is fine. Please share your mongo shell output where you get the correct result

Comment: nabeel, thx... i changed my post, please read my EDIT 2 and 'output from the console'

Comment: Added EDIT 3, it has something to do with mongo not looking in the right collection (teams vs Team)

Comment: That's the problem. When you do mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema), It maps to a collection named "teams" instead of "Team" in your DB. I guess that's a convention in mongoose.

Comment: If you need to use your own collection name you can do it like this:  mongoose.model('Team', 'Team', teamSchema); http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model

Comment: o my god that's crazy, they should tell you that in the docs. Thx, i didn't know in what places mongoose changes your stuff by convention. [collection] <String> name (optional, induced from model name)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the

```
mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/basingCOM');

var Team = mongoose.model('Team');
Team.find({"GroupName":"kevin"}, function (err, teams) {console.log(teams)})
```

to

```
var teamModel = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/basingCOM');

teamModel.find({"GroupName":"kevin"}, function (err, teams) {console.log(teams)});
```

Normally I do the differente way, but I think that this way can help you....

Comment: I still get an empty object []

Comment: I found this reference http://goo.gl/dJbHzd
It's shows your example. I think that if you connect before to create the Schema is good chance to work.